# helping with php login validation

Tags: php

What's wrong with my code causes any length of password still print out the error message?

```
<?php
if(strlen($password)<6){
        $errormsg[1][]='password length at least 6';
    }

}
?>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($errormsg[1])){
    foreach($errormsg[1] as $errorlength){
        echo "<p class='small text-danger text-center'>".$errorlength."</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How else do you set `$errormsg[1]`?  I likely wouldnt have the `1` index. `strlen` I also wouldnt be checking during login... if insecure tell them when setting it.

Comment: What is `$password`, where does it come from at this point?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet the second closing bracket is too much, but besides that - should work unless you have another snippet where you set $errormsg.

Comment: Please copy paste the code with your correction to make your answer.